# Why does R keep giving me Undefined Columns Selected Error, and when I input a value, it gives me "invalid type (NULL)"?

Tags: r, statistics

I am a total beginner on R and I have to write the lines of code as I have shown in the attached image. When writing the highlighted line, I am faced with a "undefined columns error". I wondering whats causing that issue? When I try to insert a value before the i+1, for example (crash_data[HMSP, i+1] it gives me a "invalid type (NULL) for variable" error. HMSP is the name of one of the columns within the data set I imported

Does anyone have a solution for this? I would appreciate it so much, thank you.

[Lines of Code in R I am following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMwLl.png)

[Equation (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ifwM.png)

Link to dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qDvDJg5IORAlhNJH-e1ILco38S5zI_Qz/view?usp=sharing

```
crash_data<-read.csv("Dummycsv.csv", header=T)


Residuals_expanded_model<-matrix(0,311,51)


for (i in 1:51) {

Residuals_expanded_model[,i] <- resid(lm(crash_data[,i+1] ~ 
crash_data[,53]+ crash_data[,54]+ crash_data[,55]+ crash_data[,56]+ 
crash_data[,57]))

}


firm_spe_week_retur<-log(matrix(1,311,51)+Residuals_expanded_model)


write.csv(firm_spe_week_retur,"returns_W.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Also, please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Removed Stata tag: I see no connection here.

Answer (score 0):

Is `HMSP` the actual name, or a variable storing the name? If the former, you must use `"HMSP"`. Also, the square brackets refer to `x[row, col]`

The problem is that there are NA values in your matrix and thus there are missing residuals, i.e. you try to replace the 311 elements in your matrix with only 309 values from your model: `which(is.na(crash_data), arr.ind = TRUE)`

Comment: Hi Max, I added a picture above showing what my data set looks like. HMSP is the stock ticker and all the values are under that column. Also as for x[row, col] - this would mean that the code I have to follow which is (crash_data[, i+1] must be incorrect because it doesn't indicate the row? My rows are dates starting from 22/01/2015 till 31/12/2020, however whenever I insert a date into the 'row' it still does not work.

Comment: > Residuals_expanded_model[22/01/2015:31/12/2020,i] <- resid(lm(crash_data[,i+1] ~ crash_data[,53]+ crash_data[,54]+ crash_data[,55]+ crash_data[,56]+ crash_data[,57])) Should it look like this? because its still giving me an undefined columns selected error

Comment: I believe that line of code is trying to recreate an equation for a market residual model, which I have attached in my original post above.

Comment: Ive added the lines of code which I have been inputting into R. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi max, I've tried replacing 311 with 309, however I am still getting this error "Error in `[.data.frame`(crash_data, , i + 1) : undefined columns selected". What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Your matrix dimensions just don't fit the model residual data. For example, the code runs without any problems if you replace the NA with random data (just to illustrate) `crash_data[is.na(crash_data)] <- runif(n = 3)`